# Making tiles on a web page light up different colours in a sequence

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a grid of tiles. Each tile would represent a different colour but I was wondering if there was a way I could make each tile light up in a specified sequence.

Preferably when the page loads the specified tile would show the colour specified in a sequence.

What is the best method to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This kind of sounds like homework to me.

Comment: Using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Have you tried _anything_ yet?

Comment: Use some JQuery to update the CSS on the tiles. Use setTimeout to trigger the updates.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into using JQuery to do this, this is not homework!

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. Just edit your question if you need to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsdo.it/minikomi/p1aH

Add more div and arrays to the object to get more tiles.
Not efficient but does the job!