# Trying to make tiles on a webpage light in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making tiles on a web page light up different colours in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278518/making-tiles-on-a-web-page-light-up-different-colours-in-a-sequence)

I am currently trying to light up specific tiles on a page within a 4x4 grid.

I have the grid on the page but the tiles specified to light up do not. Please can someone help me to achieve this.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="script.js">
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="square1id" class="box"></div>

    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="square2id" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

h1{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}

.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:860px;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.box{
    width:210px;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.spacing{
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var colourinfo = {
        square1id: [
                    '#000000'
                    ],

        square2id: [
                    '#ffffff'
                    ],

    };

    var count = 0;

    var changecol = function(){
        $.each(colourinfo, function(tileid, colarray){
           $('#'+tileid).css('background-color', colarray[count%colarray.length]);
        }); 
        count++;
    };

    setInterval(changecol, 1000);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You did not make an initial call to the changecol function. Since it never runs then the setInterval is never executed.

Comment: Edit your existing question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278518/making-tiles-on-a-web-page-light-up-different-colours-in-a-sequence, rather than making a new one.

Comment: this works.. I pasted it into jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/twFrB/

Comment: @jimplode  - This does not work in Google Chrome, Firefox or IE, do you know is there is anyway I could get this to work in any of the browsers? Thanks

Comment: @jimplode - Interesting, what version of FF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You've only defined one color for each `id`, so this is completely pointless.  You're going to call a method every second that does nothing but set the `background-color` to the color it already has.  Only the first call will actually do anything.  If it is supposed to cycle back and forth between different colors then you need more values in your color arrays.

Comment: I have added more values within each array but this still does not show color change. Thanks

Comment: The javascript is copied exactly from your previous question which had a working example attached and someone posted your exact code pasted into jsfiddle which also worked (although it was pointless).  I think you have some other issue.